# $2^n=C_0+C_1+\dots+C_n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, binomial-coefficients

[image: Need Hint for this]

Could anyone give me hints for this one?

$2^n=C_0+C_1+\dots+C_n$

Thats all I can say and I know tricks like  integrating or differentiating both side and then put $x=1$ or what ever we need.

but the given expression seems very critical to me. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $\displaystyle (a+b)^n=\sum_{r=0}^n\binom nr a^{n-r}b^r$

Set $a=b=1$

---

Now, $\displaystyle\frac{\binom nr}{\binom n{r+1}}=\frac{n!}{(n-r)! r!}\cdot\frac{(n-r-1)!\cdot (r+1)!}{n!}=\frac{r+1}{n-r}$

$\displaystyle\implies 1+\frac{\binom nr}{\binom n{r+1}}=1+\frac{r+1}{n-r}=\frac{n+1}{n-r}$

So, $\displaystyle\prod_{r=0}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{\binom nr}{\binom n{r+1}}\right)=\prod_{r=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{n+1}{n-r}\right)=\frac{(n+1)^n}{n!}$

Comment: How does this help with the problem? The OP already knows that $2^n = \sum_r \binom{n}{r}$, and is not looking for a proof of this fact.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, please find the edited version. Btw, have you noticed "Could anyone give me hints for this one" in the Question & the Title?

Comment: The "Could anyone give me hints for this one?" refers to the actual problem. In general, please read the question more carefully before answering. :-)