# Alternating sum of binomial coefficients is equal to zero

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, summation, binomial-coefficients

> Prove without using induction that the following formula:$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}=0$$ is valid for every $n\ge1$.

#### Progress

For each odd $n$ we can use the identity:$$\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$$ In fact all terms equidistant from the end points are opposite. My question is: if $n$ is even how can we prove it?

Comment: The standard proofs are outlined [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Alternating_Sum_and_Difference_of_Binomial_Coefficients_for_Given_n).

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634956/2n-c-0c-1-dotsc-n/634959#634959

Comment: Depending on your perspective, this fact shows that the Euler characteristic of the $n$-torus $T^n = (S^1)^n$ is zero, or it can be proven using that $\chi(T^n) = 0$.

Answer (score 38):

Set $a=1,b=-1$ in the Binomial Expansion formula for non-negative intger $n$ $$(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk a^{n-k}b^k$$

Comment: So simple yet so efficient.