# Sum of alternative binomial coefficients

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

How can I show that $\sum _{n=0}^{p-1} (-1)^n \binom{p}{n+1}=1$ where $p$ is a positive integer?

Is this the rule [for this proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Alternating_Sum_and_Difference_of_Binomial_Coefficients_for_Given_n)?

I could not figure it out [even using this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/907742/alternating-sum-of-binomial-coefficients-is-equal-to-zero).

Probably this may be a well-known result, however I could not find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the binomial theorem,
$$ 0=(1-1)^p=\sum_{j=0}^p(-1)^j{p\choose j}$$
Note that the $j=0$ term in the sum is $1$. Therefore
$$ 1=-\sum_{j=1}^p(-1)^j{p\choose j}=\sum_{j=1}^p(-1)^{j-1}{p\choose j}$$
and setting $n=j-1$, this becomes
$$ 1=\sum_{n=0}^{p-1}(-1)^n{p\choose n+1}$$

Comment: It needs a simple but smart trick, thanks @carmichael561.